# Force the redeployment of a lambda function when the underlying docker image is updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

In my cdk stack I have the following:

```py
self.image = DockerImageAsset(
    self,
    "my_image",
    directory="lambda",
)

repository = ecr.Repository(
    self,
    id="lambdas-repo",
    repository_name="myrepo",
    removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    image_scan_on_push=True,
    lifecycle_rules=[ecr.LifecycleRule(max_image_count=10)],
)

ecrdeploy.ECRDeployment(
    self,
    id="deploy_docker_image_latest",
    src=ecrdeploy.DockerImageName(self.image.image_uri),
    dest=ecrdeploy.DockerImageName(f"{repository.repository_uri}:latest"),
)

self.cleansing_lambda = _lambda.DockerImageFunction(
    self,
    "cleansing_lambda",
    function_name="FNAME",
    code=_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_ecr(
        repository, cmd=["handler"]
    ),
    timeout=Duration.seconds(60),
)
```

When I deploy this all is fine - the image is correctly uploaded to ECR in my repository, the lambda function is created and works. However, when I update the image and redeploy the stack, the lambda function is not updated even if a new image (tagged 'latest') is pushed to my ECR repository.

Is there a way to force the redeployment of the lambdas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS CDK update lambda function code when code is referenced by ECR image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65996593/aws-cdk-update-lambda-function-code-when-code-is-referenced-by-ecr-image)